# How to edit a function url string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, soundcloud

I have a function `track[0].artwork_url` that posts this:

```
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-xxxxxxx-05vmpm-large.jpg?8063923
```

But I want it to write `t500x500` instead of `large` like this:

```
http://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-xxxxxxx-05vmpm-t500x500.jpg?8063923
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using **`String.replace`** in javascript.

```
track[0].artwork_url.replace('large', 't500x500');
```